# Multiple JSON objects in the stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to execute two helper functions of in a view call the second with the return of the first.  I know the following functions properly returns the desired hash:

```
%p = helper_method0 params[:some_string] #does a request on a third party site which  responds with json data wich is then parsed by yajl and the hash is returned to view
```

However when I call the following:

```
- hash = helper_method0 params[:some_string] #does a request on a third party site which  responds with json data wich is then parsed by yajl and the hash is returned to view
%p= helper_method1 hash #Literally is just returning the input parameter
```

I receive the following error message

```
 Found multiple JSON objects in the stream but no block or the on_parse_complete callback was assigned to handle them.
```

How do I call a method with an input parameter as the return of another method from the view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is perfectly correct :)

And you could also do:
*(if you want to save bytes and variables)*

```
%p= helper_method1( helper_method0 params[:some_string] )
```

---

But anyway...
This error sounds like a problem in the json parser... are you using **Yajl**?

I have seen this issue when using Yajl like this:

```
parser = Yajl::Parser.new
hash = parser.parse(some_string)
```

What worked for me was to use the Yajl class method like this:

```
Yajl::Parser.parse(some_string.strip)
```

I hope this helps :)